# Xcode Linking Errors, RegisterAllClasses()

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, linker-errors

I'm making a game and reached the stage where I want to start my beta-testing on IOS.
Using **Unity 5.2.3f1**, the game plays without any errors whatsoever. Everything goes perfect when I build straight to our test-devices (iPhone, iPad etc), however when I try to build the game using XCODE I get blasted with deprecated warnings and RegisterAllClasses errors, they all seem to come from code generated when building the game with Unity. And I have no idea what to do with them. I've tried several google-search solutions but none successful. I even tried XCODE 7.1 beta 4.

I'm hoping I can get some help from you guys. I've pasted my XCODE logs below. 
Thanks!

```
"_UnityADBannerViewFailedToLoad", referenced from:


      -[UnityADBanner bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] in iAD.o


  "_UnityADBannerViewWasClicked", referenced from:


      -[UnityADBanner bannerViewActionDidFinish:] in iAD.o


  "_UnityADBannerViewWasLoaded", referenced from:


      -[UnityADBanner bannerViewDidLoadAd:] in iAD.o


  "_UnityADInterstitialADWasLoaded", referenced from:


      -[UnityInterstitialAd interstitialAdDidLoad:] in iAD.o


  "_UnityBindFramebuffer", referenced from:


      _CreateSystemRenderingSurfaceGLES in GlesHelper.o


      _DestroySystemRenderingSurfaceGLES in GlesHelper.o


      _CreateRenderingSurfaceGLES in GlesHelper.o


      _DestroyRenderingSurfaceGLES in GlesHelper.o


      _CreateSharedDepthbufferGLES in GlesHelper.o


      _PreparePresentGLES in GlesHelper.o


  "_UnityBlitToBackbuffer", referenced from:


      _PreparePresentGLES in GlesHelper.o


  "_UnityCaptureScreenshot", referenced from:


      _PreparePresentGLES in GlesHelper.o


  "_UnityCleanup", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController applicationWillTerminate:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnityCreateDummySurface", referenced from:


      _CreateUnityRenderBuffersGLES in GlesHelper.o


  "_UnityCreateExternalSurfaceGLES", referenced from:


      _CreateUnityRenderBuffersGLES in GlesHelper.o


  "_UnityDeliverUIEvents", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaint] in UnityAppController+Rendering.o


  "_UnityDestroyExternalSurface", referenced from:


      _DestroyUnityRenderBuffersGLES in GlesHelper.o


  "_UnityDidAccelerate", referenced from:


      ___UnityCoreMotionStart_block_invoke in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "_UnityDidCaptureVideoFrame", referenced from:


      -[CameraCaptureController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in CameraCapture.o


  "_UnityDisableDepthAndStencilBuffers", referenced from:


      EnsureDisplayIsInited(DisplayConnection*) in DisplayManager.o


      -[UnityView recreateGLESSurfaceIfNeeded] in UnityView.o


      -[UnityView recreateGLESSurface] in UnityView.o


  "_UnityDisableRenderBuffers", referenced from:


      -[DisplayManager screenDidDisconnect:] in DisplayManager.o


  "_UnityDropViewTouchProcessing", referenced from:


      -[UnityADBanner dealloc] in iAD.o


  "_UnityEndFrame", referenced from:


      _UnityRepaint in UnityAppController+Rendering.o


  "_UnityFinishRendering", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController(ViewHandling) orientInterface:] in UnityAppController+ViewHandling.o


  "_UnityGetAccelerometerFrequency", referenced from:


      _UnityCoreMotionStart in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "_UnityGetAppBackgroundBehavior", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController applicationWillResignActive:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnityGetDataContextGLES", referenced from:


      -[DisplayConnection initRendering] in DisplayManager.o


  "_UnityGetDesiredMSAASampleCount", referenced from:


      -[UnityView recreateGLESSurfaceIfNeeded] in UnityView.o


      -[UnityView recreateGLESSurface] in UnityView.o


  "_UnityGetLaunchScreenXib", referenced from:


      -[SplashScreenController create:] in SplashScreen.o


  "_UnityGetRenderingAPIs", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController(Rendering) selectRenderingAPI] in UnityAppController+Rendering.o


  "_UnityGetRenderingResolution", referenced from:


      -[UnityView recreateGLESSurfaceIfNeeded] in UnityView.o


      -[UnityView recreateGLESSurface] in UnityView.o


  "_UnityGetSRGBRequested", referenced from:


      -[UnityView recreateGLESSurfaceIfNeeded] in UnityView.o


      -[UnityView recreateGLESSurface] in UnityView.o


  "_UnityGetShowActivityIndicatorOnLoading", referenced from:


      ShowActivityIndicator(UIView*) in ActivityIndicator.o


  "_UnityGetTargetFPS", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController(Rendering) createDisplayLink] in UnityAppController+Rendering.o


  "_UnityGetTargetResolution", referenced from:


      _QueryTargetResolution in DeviceSettings.o


  "_UnityHasRenderingAPIExtension", referenced from:


      _InitRenderingGLES in GlesHelper.o


  "_UnityInitApplicationGraphics", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController startUnity:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnityInitApplicationNoGraphics", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnityInputProcess", referenced from:


      _UnityRepaint in UnityAppController+Rendering.o


  "_UnityIsCaptureScreenshotRequested", referenced from:


      _PreparePresentGLES in GlesHelper.o


  "_UnityIsOrientationEnabled", referenced from:


      -[UnityDefaultViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations] in UnityViewControllerBase.o


  "_UnityIsPaused", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController(UnityInterface) paused] in UnityAppController+UnityInterface.o


      -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaint] in UnityAppController+Rendering.o


      -[MPVideoContext finish] in MPVideoPlayer.o


      -[UnityView didRotate] in UnityView.o


      -[UnityView recreateGLESSurface] in UnityView.o


      -[UnityAppController applicationDidBecomeActive:] in UnityAppController.o


      -[UnityAppController(ViewHandling) showGameUI] in UnityAppController+ViewHandling.o


      ...


  "_UnityLoadApplication", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController startUnity:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnityOnApplicationWillResignActive", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController applicationWillResignActive:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnityParseCommandLine", referenced from:


      _main in main.o


  "_UnityPause", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController(UnityInterface) setPaused:] in UnityAppController+UnityInterface.o


      -[MPVideoContext initAndPlay:bgColor:control:scaling:cancelOnTouch:] in MPVideoPlayer.o


      -[MPVideoContext finish] in MPVideoPlayer.o


      -[UnityAppController applicationDidBecomeActive:] in UnityAppController.o


      -[UnityAppController applicationWillResignActive:] in UnityAppController.o


      -[UnityADBanner bannerViewActionShouldBegin:willLeaveApplication:] in iAD.o


      -[UnityADBanner bannerViewActionDidFinish:] in iAD.o


      ...


     (maybe you meant: _UnityPauseCameraCapture)


  "_UnityPlayerLoop", referenced from:


      _UnityRepaint in UnityAppController+Rendering.o


  "_UnityRegisterFBO", referenced from:


      _CreateUnityRenderBuffersGLES in GlesHelper.o


  "_UnityReportAVCapturePermission", referenced from:


      ___UnityRequestAVCapturePermission_block_invoke in AVCapture.o


  "_UnityReportBackbufferChange", referenced from:


      -[UnityView recreateGLESSurface] in UnityView.o


  "_UnityReportResizeView", referenced from:


      -[UnityView onUpdateSurfaceSize:] in UnityView.o


  "_UnityReportWWWFailedWithError", referenced from:


      -[UnityWWWConnectionDelegate connection:didFailWithError:] in WWWConnection.o


  "_UnityReportWWWFinishedLoadingData", referenced from:


      -[UnityWWWConnectionDelegate finishProcessing] in WWWConnection.o


  "_UnityReportWWWReceivedData", referenced from:


      -[UnityWWWConnectionDelegate connection:didReceiveData:] in WWWConnection.o


  "_UnityReportWWWReceivedResponse", referenced from:


      -[UnityWWWConnectionDelegate connection:didReceiveResponse:] in WWWConnection.o


  "_UnityReportWWWSentData", referenced from:


      -[UnityWWWConnectionDelegate connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:] in WWWConnection.o


  "_UnityReportWWWStatusError", referenced from:


      -[UnityWWWConnectionDelegate connection:didReceiveResponse:] in WWWConnection.o


  "_UnityRequestRenderingResolution", referenced from:


      _UnityInitMainScreenRenderingCallback in UnityAppController+Rendering.o


      _UnityDisplayManager_SetRenderingResolution in DisplayManager.o


  "_UnityRequestedScreenOrientation", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController(ViewHandling) createRootViewController] in UnityAppController+ViewHandling.o


      -[UnityAppController(ViewHandling) checkOrientationRequest] in UnityAppController+ViewHandling.o


  "_UnitySendDeviceToken", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnitySendLocalNotification", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in UnityAppController.o


      -[UnityAppController application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnitySendRemoteNotification", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:] in UnityAppController.o


      -[UnityAppController application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnitySendRemoteNotificationError", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnitySendTouchesBegin", referenced from:


      -[UnityView touchesBegan:withEvent:] in UnityView.o


  "_UnitySendTouchesCancelled", referenced from:


      -[UnityView touchesCancelled:withEvent:] in UnityView.o


  "_UnitySendTouchesEnded", referenced from:


      -[UnityView touchesEnded:withEvent:] in UnityView.o


  "_UnitySendTouchesMoved", referenced from:


      -[UnityView touchesMoved:withEvent:] in UnityView.o


  "_UnitySensorsSetAttitude", referenced from:


      _UnityUpdateGyroData in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "_UnitySensorsSetGravity", referenced from:


      _UnityUpdateGyroData in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "_UnitySensorsSetGyroRotationRate", referenced from:


      _UnityUpdateGyroData in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "_UnitySensorsSetGyroRotationRateUnbiased", referenced from:


      _UnityUpdateGyroData in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "_UnitySensorsSetUserAcceleration", referenced from:


      _UnityUpdateGyroData in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "_UnitySetJoystickPosition", referenced from:


      _UnityUpdateJoystickData in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "_UnitySetKeyState", referenced from:


      SetJoystickButtonState(int, int, int) in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "_UnitySetLogEntryHandler", referenced from:


      UnityInitTrampoline() in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnitySetPlayerFocus", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController startUnity:] in UnityAppController.o


      -[UnityAppController applicationDidBecomeActive:] in UnityAppController.o


      -[UnityAppController applicationWillResignActive:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnitySetViewTouchProcessing", referenced from:


      -[KeyboardDelegate init] in Keyboard.o


      -[UnityADBanner initImpl:layout:type:] in iAD.o


  "_UnityShouldAutorotate", referenced from:


      -[UnityDefaultViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations] in UnityViewControllerBase.o


      -[UnityAppController(ViewHandling) createRootViewController] in UnityAppController+ViewHandling.o


      -[UnityAppController(ViewHandling) checkOrientationRequest] in UnityAppController+ViewHandling.o


  "_UnityStartFrame", referenced from:


      _UnityRepaint in UnityAppController+Rendering.o


     (maybe you meant: _UnityStartFrameRendering)


  "_UnityStringToKey", referenced from:


      SetJoystickButtonState(int, int, int) in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "_UnityUpdateDisplayList", referenced from:


      -[DisplayManager updateDisplayListInUnity] in DisplayManager.o


  "_UnityUseAnimatedAutorotation", referenced from:


      WillRotateToInterfaceOrientation_DefaultImpl(objc_object*, objc_selector*, UIInterfaceOrientation, double) in UnityViewControllerBase.o


      ViewWillTransitionToSize_DefaultImpl(objc_object*, objc_selector*, CGSize, id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>) in UnityViewControllerBase.o


  "_UnityWillPause", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController applicationWillResignActive:] in UnityAppController.o


  "_UnityWillResume", referenced from:


      -[UnityAppController applicationDidBecomeActive:] in UnityAppController.o


  "Register_UnityEngine_SocialPlatforms_GameCenter_GameCenterPlatform_Internal_ShowSpecificLeaderboardUI()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllStrippedInternalCalls() in UnityICallRegistration.o


  "Register_UnityEngine_SocialPlatforms_GameCenter_GameCenterPlatform_Internal_LoadAchievementDescriptions()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllStrippedInternalCalls() in UnityICallRegistration.o


  "Register_UnityEngine_SocialPlatforms_GameCenter_GameCenterPlatform_Internal_ShowDefaultAchievementBanner()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllStrippedInternalCalls() in UnityICallRegistration.o


  "RegisterModule_UI()", referenced from:


      RegisterStaticallyLinkedModulesGranular() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Font()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Mesh()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "UnitySetLastHeading(float, float, float, float, float, double)", referenced from:


      -[LocationServiceDelegate locationManager:didUpdateHeading:] in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "RegisterClass_Camera()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Canvas()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Motion()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Shader()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Sprite()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterModule_Audio()", referenced from:


      RegisterStaticallyLinkedModulesGranular() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "UnitySetLastLocation(double, float, float, float, float, float)", referenced from:


      -[LocationServiceDelegate locationManager:didUpdateLocations:] in iPhone_Sensors.o


  "RegisterClass_Cubemap()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Texture()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "il2cpp_gc_alloc_fixed(unsigned long, void*)", referenced from:


      g_mscorlib_Assembly_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o


      Object_t_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o


      Object_t_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator_Object__ctor_m1_0(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o


      Object_t_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator_Object_Finalize_m1_3(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o


      Object_t_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator_Object_ReferenceEquals_m1_8(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o


      ValueType_t1_1_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o


      Attribute_t1_2_CustomAttributesCacheGenerator(CustomAttributesCache*) in Il2CppAttributes.o


      ...


  "RegisterClass_Animator()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Collider()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_GUILayer()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Material()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Renderer()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterModule_Physics()", referenced from:


      RegisterStaticallyLinkedModulesGranular() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_AudioClip()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Behaviour()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Component()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_TextAsset()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Texture2D()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Texture3D()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Transform()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Collider2D()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_FlareLayer()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_GameObject()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_MeshFilter()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_MonoScript()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_SampleClip()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_TagManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterModule_Animation()", referenced from:


      RegisterStaticallyLinkedModulesGranular() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterModule_Physics2D()", referenced from:


      RegisterStaticallyLinkedModulesGranular() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_AssetBundle()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_AudioSource()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_CanvasGroup()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_GameManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_LightProbes()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_MonoManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_NamedObject()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_PreloadData()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_TimeManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_AudioManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_InputManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_ScriptMapper()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_AnimationClip()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_AudioListener()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_BuildSettings()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_MonoBehaviour()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_RectTransform()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_RenderTexture()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "il2cpp_array_addr_with_size(Il2CppArray*, int, unsigned long)", referenced from:


      Il2CppArray* il2cpp::vm::PlatformInvoke::MarshalArrayResult<int>(TypeInfo*, int*, unsigned long) in Bulk_System_1.o


      Il2CppArray* il2cpp::vm::PlatformInvoke::MarshalArrayResult<int>(TypeInfo*, int*, unsigned long) in Bulk_mscorlib_2.o


      Il2CppArray* il2cpp::vm::PlatformInvoke::MarshalArrayResult<unsigned char>(TypeInfo*, unsigned char*, unsigned long) in Bulk_mscorlib_4.o


      Il2CppArray* il2cpp::vm::PlatformInvoke::MarshalArrayResult<unsigned char>(TypeInfo*, unsigned char*, unsigned long) in Bulk_mscorlib_5.o


  "RegisterClass_AudioBehaviour()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_CanvasRenderer()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_DirectorPlayer()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_NetworkManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_PhysicsManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_PlayerSettings()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_RenderSettings()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_SpriteRenderer()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterModule_TextRendering()", referenced from:


      RegisterStaticallyLinkedModulesGranular() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_EditorExtension()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_QualitySettings()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_ResourceManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_GraphicsSettings()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_LevelGameManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_LightmapSettings()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_GlobalGameManager()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "RegisterClass_Physics2DSettings()", referenced from:


      RegisterAllClasses() in UnityClassRegistration.o


  "Register_UnityEngine_Event_Init()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Mesh_Clear()", referenced from:


  "RegisterClass_AnimatorController()", referenced from:


  "RegisterClass_DelayedCallManager()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Object_get_name()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Object_set_name()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_RectOffset_Init()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Camera_get_depth()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Font_get_dynamic()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_GUIStyle_Cleanup()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Gradient_Cleanup()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Input_GetAxisRaw()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Mesh_get_normals()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_PlayerPrefs_Save()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Random_get_value()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Screen_get_width()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Camera_get_aspect()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Event_get_keyCode()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Event_get_rawType()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Font_HasCharacter()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Font_get_fontSize()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Font_get_material()", referenced from:


  "Register_UnityEngine_Font_set_material()", referenced from:
  "Register_UnityEngine_GUIStyle_get_name()", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've spoken too soon. I have no proper answer for the errors posted, however downloading the new version of Unity (5.3) fixed all my problems. The app built without errors.

Thanks again!